# Dynamics 365 FetchXml is ignoring system setting for first day of week when filtered on last-week

Tags: dynamics-crm, fetchxml

I'm using FetchXml to query Dynamics 365 data based on last-week and it's not giving me the results I expect. It seems to be hard-coded to give Sunday to Saturday but we have defined the first day of the week for our organisation as Monday.

Consequently my FetchXml query gives a different result to what I get when I run an Advanced Find query in CRM itself. Is there any way of making it pick up the system setting for first day of the week?

If it makes any difference, I'm running the FetchXml query from an Azure Function. I have set the time zone on that to AEST but, given that this is an organisation setting, I'm not sure that should matter.

Thanks for your help

Mick

Comment: I just tried in one of my trial instance and it works fine for me both in Advanced find and Fetchxml builder. By default start of week was Sunday, it did gave correct results and when changed to Monday it gave correct result on both advanced find and fetchxml builder. My field was Date and Time field.

Comment: Thanks for trying that. Do you have any suggestions for when it doesn't work?

Comment: What user account is the Azure Function connecting to CRM as?

Comment: It's connecting as the system administrator account. Will that make a difference?

Comment: what is giving your correct result? Advanced find or fetchxml? Also note that crm saves dates as UTC but displays as local user depending on how you configured your field.

Comment: Advanced Find is giving me the correct Monday to Sunday results. Fetchxml is giving me the results for Sunday to Saturday which is not what I want :)

Comment: I've tried changing my organisation settings for First day of Week back to Sunday, confirmed that then my Advanced Find and Fetchxml both give the same result, then changed it back to Monday and my Advanced Find changes but the FetchXml doesn't. What am I missing?